# Define UNIQUE key constraint for the table

Tags: php

I have implemented this code to insert and update the data in my database but when I try it a new  row's data is always being inserted in the table and it is not being updated How can I define the unique key in my case to get it to work? I have the primary key id.

```
<?php

$json = '{"latitude":53.86898451,"longitude":10.66561387,"route":4}';

$data = json_decode ( $json );

$route = "route_" . $data->{'route'};
$latitude = $data->{'latitude'};
$longitude = $data->{'longitude'};

require 'connection.php';

// check whether route's table exist.
$results = $con->query ( "SHOW TABLES LIKE'" . $route . "'" ) or die ( mysqli_error () );

if (($results->num_rows) == 1) {
  //"UPDATE MyGuests SET lastname='Doe' WHERE id=2"
 $sql = "INSERT INTO ".$route."(latitude, longitude, created_at)
          VALUES( ? , ? , NOW() )
          ON DUPLICATE KEY 
          UPDATE latitude = VALUES(latitude)
               , longitude = VALUES(longitude)";

  $stmt = $con->prepare($sql) or die ( $con->error );
  $stmt->bind_param("ss",$latitude,$longitude);
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();

  echo "Table exist";
} else {
  $create =  "CREATE TABLE " . $route . "
       (id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY UNIQUE,
     latitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL, 
     longitude FLOAT(10,6) NOT NULL,
     created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)" ;
   $stmt = $con->prepare($create) or die ( $con->error );
  $stmt->execute();

  $stmt->close();


  echo "table was craeted";
}
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I'm trying now

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ".$route."(id, latitude, longitude, created_at)
      VALUES( id, ? , ? , NOW() )
      ON DUPLICATE KEY 
      UPDATE latitude = VALUES(latitude)
           , longitude = VALUES(longitude)";
```

Which variable should I add in the VALUES braces for id?

Comment: How is it supposed to know which row to update? Shouldn't your table have a `route` column?

Comment: BTW: You don't need to say `UNIQUE` for the primary key, it's always unique. And you don't need to insert the `created_at` column, since it defaults to the current time.

Comment: @Barmar: I am not getting what you are to? I have to add the route column in my table just to get it to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not specifying a value for `id` in your INSERT INTO statement, so there will never be a duplicate key.

Instead, it is auto-generating the next available ID.

To solve this, specify the value of the pre-existing ID (if any).

Comment: and which vairiable should I add in the `VALUES` braces for id? please see my updated code.

Comment: Please don't edit your question to disguise the original problem.  Instead, add on to the end with your updated attempt.  On the surface your edit looks like it should work, assuming you have the `id` saved from having previously selected it out of the database.  There is not enough of your code in the question to know if that is happening, or where you are saving it.

Comment: I edited your question to restore the original version, and added your changes to the end.

Comment: Ok I will never  change it again.This is the whole code I have in my php script plus the connection.php file, which just contains the connection statement. In my mysql I just have one database in it the `route_4` table is being created. My databe consists of the `route_4` table.